# How to restore a MySQL InnoDB with ONLY .ibd files?

Tags: innodb, recovery, mysql-8.0

I had a Bitnami Joomla! stack running on a computer that suddenly kicked the bucket. I had neglected to make a back-up before this happened so I do not have any dumps or backed up files, but was able to save the directory and everything in it when I recovered its hard drive. I was a fool and wiped the recovered drive after removing the files I wanted to keep, so I can't go back to get anything else....

I've been trying to recover the tables (76 in total) into a live MySQL installation to get access to them, create a back up and import them into a fresh stack to restore my site. I have saved every .ibd in the database's folder, along with ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, ibdata1, mysql.ibd, binlog.index, etc. My installation never had a .frm file that so many posts mention having, and it never did even when it was live. I do not know the tables' structures in order to replace them one by one, and Joomla's documentation on them is apparently outdated.

My installation used MySQL 8.0.21, running under Windows 10. I would really appreciate help to solve this issue. I've looked for tutorials on how to fix my issues, but they were either for prior versions of MySQL (which I am unfamiliar with compatibility) or required a back-up or that .frm file (which I don't have). Additionally, I compared my saved directory with a fresh install of the same stack installer 3.9.22-0, and the base install did not have a .frm file from what I remember. I tried importing the raw .ibd files through phpMyAdmin and had no luck there either.

I can offer more details if necessary. Thank you for any help you can offer me!

Comment: You may try: 1. Create the table with precisely the same structure 2. Drop its tablespace 3. Stop server and replace empty .IBD with your .IBD with the data 4. Start server 5. Import tablespace from replaced .IBD. PS. The MySQL version must be precisely the same.

Comment: @Akina I'll give that a try! Thank you for your suggestion.